# How can I replace an image in Google Documents?

Tags: image, google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm trying to insert images into Google Docs (other GSuite apps later) from an Add-On.  I've succeeded in fetching the image and inserting it when getCursor() returns a valid Position.  When there is a selection (instead of a Cursor), I can succeed if it's text that's selected by walking up to the Parent of the selected text and inserting the image at the start of the paragraph (not perfect, but OK).

UPDATE: It seems that I was using a deprecated method (`getSelectedElements()`), but that didn't fix the issue.  It seems the issue is only with **wrapped** images as well (I didn't realize that the type of the object changed when you changed it to a wrapped text).

However, when an wrapped-text Image (presumably a `PositionedImage`) is highlighted (with the rotate and resize handles visible in blue), both `getSelection()` and `getCursor()` return `null`.  This is a problem as I would like to be able to get that image and replace it with the one I'm inserting.

Here's my code... any help would be great.

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(imageTokenURL);
var selection = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getSelection();
if (selection)
{
  Logger.log("Got Selection");
  var replaced = false;
  var elements = selection.getRangeElements();
  if (elements.length === 1
      && elements[0].getElement().getType() === DocumentApp.ElementType.INLINE_IMAGE)
  {
    //replace the URL -- this never happens
  }
  //otherwise, we take the first element and work from there:
  var firstElem = elements[0].getElement();
  Logger.log("First Element Type = " + firstElem.getType());
  if (firstElem.getType() == DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH)
  {
    var newImage = firstElem.asParagraph().insertInlineImage(0, response);
    newImage.setHeight(200);
    newImage.setWidth(200);
  }
  else if (firstElem.getType() == DocumentApp.ElementType.TEXT)
  {
    var p = firstElem.getParent();
    if (p.getType() == DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH)
    {
      var index = p.asParagraph().getChildIndex(firstElem);
      var newImage = p.asParagraph().insertInlineImage(index, response);
      newImage.setHeight(200);
      newImage.setWidth(200);
    }
  }
} else {  
  Logger.log("Checking Cursor");
  var cursor = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getCursor();
  if (cursor)
  {
    Logger.log("Got Cursor: " + cursor);
    var newImage = cursor.insertInlineImage(response);
    var p = cursor.getElement();
    var size=200;

    newImage.setHeight(size);
    newImage.setWidth(size);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the deprecated 'getSelectedElements()' method of the Range class. You may notice it's crossed out in the autocomplete selection box. 
Instead, use the 'getRangeElements()' method. After selecting the image in the doc, the code below worked for me:

```
  var range = doc.getSelection();

  var element = range.getRangeElements()[0].getElement();

  Logger.log(element.getType() == DocumentApp.ElementType.INLINE_IMAGE); //logs 'true'
```

Comment: While it's true I was using a deprecated method, that did not change the result.  I believe what's happening is that setting the image to "wrap text" changes the type of the object.  So what I'm seeing is that InlineImages objects become PositionedImage objects.  And THESE are what are not being returned as either a selection or a cursor.  I will update the question

Comment: If by "the result" you mean 'getSelection()' returning 'null', I'm out of ideas. I tested the above code on the selected instance of InlineImage and it works perfectly.